# Slow MDX count when expanding query

Tags: mdx

Trying to create a calculated measure to be used in a KPI. The measure should count all the calls (servicedesk tickets) that have a runtime larger than 7 days.

Tested the measure with this query, which runs fast (< 3 seconds).

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Count of Calls long runtime] AS         
        Count(
            Filter(
                [Call Details].[Call Number].MEMBERS
                , [Measures].[Closed Call Run Time (days)] > 7
            )
        )
SELECT
    {
        [Count of Calls long runtime]
    } ON 0
FROM
    [Business Intelligence]
```

However when adding other members to the query, suddenly it takes forever to complete:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Count of Calls long runtime] AS         
Count(
    Filter(
        (
            {
                [Ipc Categorisation].[Categorisation].[Subcategory].&[222]
                ,[Ipc Categorisation].[Categorisation].[Subcategory].&[484]
            }
            , [Call Details].[Call Number].[Call Number].MEMBERS
        )
        , [Measures].[Closed Call Run Time (days)] > 7
    )
)
SELECT
    {
        [Count of Calls long runtime]
    } ON 0
    ,
    {
        [Customer].[Customer].[Customer]
    } ON 1
FROM
    [Business Intelligence]
WHERE
    [Date].[Month Calendar].[Year].&[2016]
```

There should be about 40 of 30000 calls showing up, divided over 50 customers.

When I change [Count of Calls long runtime] to another measure (calculated or in fact table), the query runs fast.

I would like to understand why this is happening. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`FILTER` is at best avoided. It forces calculations to run in cell by cell mode. Let's try to change the calculation to run in block computation mode:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].IsGrt7 AS
IIF
 (
     [Measures].[Closed Call Run Time (days)] > 7,
     1,
     NULL
 )

MEMBER [Measures].[Count of Calls long runtime] AS         
SUM
  (        
   {
    [Ipc Categorisation].[Categorisation].[Subcategory].&[222]
    ,[Ipc Categorisation].[Categorisation].[Subcategory].&[484]
   } * [Call Details].[Call Number].[Call Number].MEMBERS
   ,
  [Measures].IsGrt7         
 )
```

To read more on this subject, [see here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/11/22/optimizing-count-filter-expressions-in-mdx.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Also worth trying feeding it into a nonempty named set before hitting the caculation:

```
WITH 
SET [CallNonEmpty] AS
NONEMPTY(
   {
      [Ipc Categorisation].[Categorisation].[Subcategory].&[222]
     ,[Ipc Categorisation].[Categorisation].[Subcategory].&[484]
   } 
  *[Call Details].[Call Number].[Call Number].MEMBERS
 , [Measures].[Closed Call Run Time (days)]
)
MEMBER [Measures].[Count of Calls long runtime] AS
SUM(
   EXISTING [CallNonEmpty], 
   IIF(
     [Measures].[Closed Call Run Time (days)] > 7
    ,1
    ,NULL
   )
)         
SELECT
   [Count of Calls long runtime] ON 0,
   [Customer].[Customer].[Customer] ON 1
FROM [Business Intelligence]
WHERE
   [Date].[Month Calendar].[Year].&[2016];
```